# AngularJs, Phonegap, Router and uiRouter

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, cordova, angular-ui-router

This is driving me crazy.

I have a HREF within one of my pages

```
<a href="#/EventAdd">Click me ## ;)</a>
```

Which works fine on chrome but not within PhoneGap on android.

I have searched around and cannot find a solution any where.

State provider config for EventAdd shown below.

```
app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  // For any unmatched url, redirect to /state1
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/home");
  //
  // Now set up the states
  $stateProvider
  .state('EventAdd', {
    url: "/EventAdd",
    templateUrl: "views/eventAdd.html",
    controller: 'EventaddCtrl'
  });
});
```

It displays no errors and just doesn't navigate off the screen.

any tips?

Answer (score 1):

Try `<a ui-sref="EventAdd">Click me ## ;)</a>` instead. Without a Plunker, i'm not sure what the issue is.

Update:

Another alternative.

**View**:

`<a ng-click="goToEventAdd()">Click me ## ;)</a>`

**Controller**:

```
$scope.goToEventAdd = function(){
    //Don't forget to inject the $state service
    $state.go("EventAdd");
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the limited information, I didnt make a Plunker as it works fine on the computer, It's only when it's complied by phone gapp it doesn't work.